# Swift extension on generic struct based on properties of type T

Tags: swift, generics

If I have a generic struct like...

```
struct Blah<T> {
    let someProperty: T
}
```

Can I then extend `Blah` to conform to `Equatable` only when `T` is `Equatable`. Like...

```
extension Blah: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Blah, rhs: Blah) -> Bool {
        return lhs.someProperty == rhs.someProperty
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

I have tried a few different ways of coding this but each gives me a slightly different error.

Comment: That is on the to-do list for Swift 4: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md.

Comment: @MartinR ok, cool, thanks. Will wait for the Swift 4 proper release and work around it for now :D Thanks :D

Comment: Unfortunately it won't be implemented for Swift 4.0, but will be in for some other version 4.x – https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/872211469856722944

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:** Conditional conformance has been implemented in Swift 4.1,
and your code

```
struct Blah<T> {
    let someProperty: T
}

extension Blah: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Blah, rhs: Blah) -> Bool {
        return lhs.someProperty == rhs.someProperty
    }
}
```

compiles and works as expected in Xcode 9.3.

---

What you are looking for is

- [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md)

(which in turn is part of the ["Generics Manifesto"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#conditional-conformances-)).
The proposal has been accepted for Swift 4 but not yet implemented.
From the proposal:

> Conditional conformances express the notion that a generic type will conform to a particular protocol only when its type arguments meet certain requirements.

and a prominent example is

```
extension Array: Equatable where Element: Equatable {
  static func ==(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Array<Element>) -> Bool { ... }
}
```

to make arrays of equatable elements equatable, which is not possible
at present. Your example is essentially

```
struct SomeWrapper<Wrapped> {
  let wrapped: Wrapped
}

extension SomeWrapper: Equatable where Wrapped: Equatable {
  static func ==(lhs: SomeWrapper<Wrapped>, rhs: SomeWrapper<Wrapper>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.wrapped == rhs.wrapped
  }
}
```

from that proposal.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that I had almost exactly copied the proposed change example :D Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Fogmeister: Conditional conformance has been implemented in Swift 4.1.