# Swift: extend optional string to conform to protocol

Tags: swift, constraints, protocols, option-type

I want optional String to conform to a protocol, not sure about the syntax. I tried this:

```
extension Optional: ObserverType where Wrapped: String
```

Not working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Conditional conformance isn't implemented yet, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584237/swift-extension-on-generic-struct-based-on-properties-of-type-t

Comment: This should work now, conditional conformance has been implemented in Swift 4.1.