# Make generic type Type<T> conform to a protocol only if T conforms to that protocol

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm trying to extend the `Optional` type to make it `DataConvertible` (a protocol that I have declared somewhere else in my code) by adding protocol conformance to it only if the `Wrapped` type conforms to the same protocol.

I tried this:

```
extension Optional: DataConvertible where Wrapped == DataConvertible { ... }
```

but then I get the error:

> Extension of type 'Optional' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause

Is there any way to achieve this with the current version of Swift?

Comment: You'll have to wait until [Swift 4.2 for conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md).

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584237/swift-extension-on-generic-struct-based-on-properties-of-type-t

Comment: Note that the meat of conditional conformances made it into Swift 4.1, however runtime casting support for them didn't make it until 4.2.